# Handling keydown event on just one Vue Router page

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

In my Vue.js SPA, I have one page where I'd like to implement keyboard interaction. I use Vue Router to facilitate linking.

So far I registered

```
const interactiveComponent = {
    //
    methods: {
        handleKeyboard(event) {
            // do something
        }
    },
    created() {
        document.addEventListener('keydown', this.handleKeyboard);
    },
    //
};
```

The problem is that when I leave that page, the handler is still active.

Even worse problem is that when I visit that page, then leave and come back, the handler is registered again and my event runs twice.

Does any convention exist in Vue.js to accomodate this kind of handler?

Comment: `removeListener` in the `destroyed()` life cycle hook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to remove that event listener in the `beforeDestroy` or `destroyed` hook ..

```
const interactiveComponent = {
    //
    methods: {
        handleKeyboard(event) {
            // do something
        }
    },
    created() {
        document.addEventListener('keydown', this.handleKeyboard);
    },
    beforeDestroy() {
        document.removeEventListener('keydown', this.handleKeyboard);
    },
};
```

Comment: Awesome! It works perfectly. I thought there is some automated way in Vue Router, but simple `removeEventListener()` when destroying the component will do.